# How do I get Get-Item to return a properly formatted registry path?

Tags: powershell, syntax, registry

The following command returns $false every time because Get-Item returns a registry path that is not correctly formatted.

```
Get-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\*" | Test-Path "$($_.Name)\Test"
```

Get-Item will return paths that start with HKEY_CURRENT_USER, rather than the HKCU: formatted path it itself uses. For example:

```
C:\>(Get-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Adobe").Name
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe
C:\>
```

Test-Path and other Powershell cmdlets cannot recognize registry paths in this format. Test-Path will therefore return False, even if the path exists.

How can I get Get-Item to return a registry path which it itself is compatible with?

Comment: It sounds like I oversimplified the example then. I want to be able to modify the path before I test it.

Comment: @Strill, I think Santiago is right.  Unlike what you are expressing in the question, Get-Item doesn't return either HKCU: or HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but instead it returns objects that in turn can be piped directly into Test-Path's input.  No need for `$_.Name`, Test-Path already knows how to handle the objects it is receiving from Get-Item.

Comment: That doesn't do me any good, because I need a path I can modify.

Comment: I updated the example to be more clear.

Comment: I think you will have to build it.  Something like this: `Get-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\*" | Foreach-Object {$_.Name -replace "^.+?\\", "$($_.PSDrive):\"} | Test-Path`

Answer (score 3):

The `.Name` property of items returned by PowerShell's registry [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) returns *registry-native* paths, which aren't directly recognized by PowerShell provider cmdlets such as [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item), [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), or [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path).

However, the items are decorated with provider-supplied [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) properties that include the `.PSPath` property, which contains the respective provider's *native* path (such as a native *registry* path) *prefixed with the PowerShell provider name* at hand, followed by  `::`; e.g., 
`Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft`<sup>[1]</sup>

Such a *provider-qualified path* IS recognized by provider cmdlets, so you can do the following, for instance:

```bash
Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Software\* |
  Test-Path -LiteralPath { "$($_.PSPath)\Test" }
```

<sup>Note: The alternative to `"$($_.PSPath)\Test"` is `Join-Path $_.PSPath Test`</sup>

Note the use of a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to make `Test-Path`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter operate on *each pipeline input object*.

---

<sup>[1] This is the equivalent of the PowerShell-native-drive-based path `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft`.

Perhaps surprisingly, the input drive specification is *not* preserved in the `.PSPath` property value.

However, with extra effort you can *reconstruct* the input path via the `.PSDrive` ETS property, if necessary.

To obtain a given path's provider prefix, use

`(Get-Item $somePath).PSProvider.Name`

To further eliminate ambiguity by including the name of the implementing *module* in the provider prefix, use the following to determine such a module-qualified provider prefix:

`(Get-Item $somePath).PSProvider | ForEach-Object { '{0}\{1}' -f $_.ModuleName, $_.Name }`</sup>